# How to split a large file into chunks in c#?

Tags: c#, file, tcp, filestream

I'm making a simple file transfer sender and receiver app through the wire. What I have so far is that the sender converts the file into a byte array and sends chunks of that array to the receiver.

This works with file of up to `256mb`, but this line throws a "System out of memory" exception for anything above:

```
byte[] buffer = StreamFile(fileName); //This is where I convert the file
```

I'm looking for a way to read the file in chunks then write that chunk instead of loading the whole file into a `byte`. How can I do this with a `FileStream`?

EDIT:

Sorry, heres my crappy code so far:

```
    private void btnSend(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fName); //file name
        byte[] fileData = null;
        try
        {
             fileData = StreamFile(textBox1.Text); //file
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Out of memory");
            return;
        }

        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length); //length of file name
        clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length + fileData.Length];
        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
        fileName.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
        fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileName.Length);
        clientSock.Connect("172.16.12.91", 9050);
        clientSock.Send(clientData, 0, 4 + fileName.Length, SocketFlags.None);

        for (int i = 4 + fileName.Length; i < clientData.Length; i++)
        {
            clientSock.Send(clientData, i, 1 , SocketFlags.None);
        }

        clientSock.Close();
    }
```

And here's how I receive (the code was from a tutorial)

```
   public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        int fileNameLen = 1;
        String content = String.Empty;
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {

            if (flag == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 4, fileNameLen);
                receivedPath = fileName;
                flag++;
            }
                if (flag >= 1)
                {
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath, FileMode.Append));
                    if (flag == 1)
                    {
                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 4 + fileNameLen, bytesRead - (4 + fileNameLen));
                        flag++;
                    }
                    else
                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        writer.Close();
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
        }
        else
        {
            Invoke(new MyDelegate(LabelWriter));
        }

    }
```

I just really want to know how I can read the file in chunks so that I dont need  to convert it to a byte.

Thanks for the responses so far, I think I'm starting to get it :D

Comment: no such method found **StreamFile**, can you tell me which library should I include?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just call `Read` repeatedly with a small buffer (I tend to use something like 16K). Note that the call to `Read` may end up reading a *smaller* amount than you request. If you're using a fixed chunk size and need the whole chunk in memory, you could just use an array of that size of course.

Without knowing how you're *sending* the file, it's hard to give much advice about how to structure your code, but it could be something like this:

```
byte[] chunk = new byte[MaxChunkSize];
while (true)
{
    int index = 0;
    // There are various different ways of structuring this bit of code.
    // Fundamentally we're trying to keep reading in to our chunk until
    // either we reach the end of the stream, or we've read everything we need.
    while (index < chunk.Length)
    {
        int bytesRead = stream.Read(chunk, index, chunk.Length - index);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        index += bytesRead;
    }
    if (index != 0) // Our previous chunk may have been the last one
    {
        SendChunk(chunk, index); // index is the number of bytes in the chunk
    }
    if (index != chunk.Length) // We didn't read a full chunk: we're done
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I was more awake I'd probably find a more readable way of writing this, but it'll do for now. One option is to extract another method from the middle section:

```
// Attempts to read an entire chunk into the given array; returns the size of
// chunk actually read.
int ReadChunk(Stream stream, byte[] chunk)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < chunk.Length)
    {
        int bytesRead = stream.Read(chunk, index, chunk.Length - index);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        index += bytesRead;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var b = new byte[1<<15]; // 32k
while((count = inStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
{
  outStream.Write(b, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static IEnumerable<byte[]> SplitStreamIntoChunks(Stream stream, int chunkSize)
    {
      var bytesRemaining = stream.Length;
      while (bytesRemaining > 0)
      {
        var size = Math.Min((int) bytesRemaining, chunkSize);
        var buffer = new byte[size];
        var bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
        if (bytesRead <= 0)
          break;
        yield return buffer;
        bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
      }
    }
```