# how to write json file with size limit (100KB) and once size cross, write new file?

Tags: c#, json.net, blockingcollection

I have a `blocking` collection which gets filled with data by some `app1`.

I have subscribed to that `blocking` collection and need to write a file with below case,

1. start writing a file .
2. if the file size crossed 100kb, close the first file and starts a new file.
3. and if there is no data coming from `app1`, lets say for 1 minute, then close the file.

Currently with below code, I'm only able to write per `blocking` collection into per file, how to proceed with my above requirement, please suggest.

```
class Program
{
    private static BlockingCollection<Message> messages = new BlockingCollection<Message>();
    private static void Producer()
    {
        int ctr = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            messages.Add(new Message { Id = ctr, Name = $"Name-{ctr}" });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ctr++;
        }
    }

    private static void Consumer()
    {
        foreach (var message in messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));

            using (var streamWriter = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(@"C:\TEMP", $"File-{ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.json")))
            {
                using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
                {
                    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    writer.WriteStartObject();
                    writer.WritePropertyName("Data");
                    writer.WriteStartArray();
                    writer.WriteRawValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
                    writer.WriteEndArray();
                    writer.WriteEndObject();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Producer());
        var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consumer());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `FileInfo.Length`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a large file into chunks in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659189/how-to-split-a-large-file-into-chunks-in-c)

Comment: Is it Kb or KB?

Comment: it's KB (KiloByte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take the messages with any size and divided it to a different  JSON file. You need to specify the size using maxchar. before that, you have to check the size of the last file like this and you have to pass the same file name and the new size if else create a new file and divide the message.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;



using System.Collections;


using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string last_path = "";
        public static readonly string BYE = "bye";
        private static BlockingCollection<Message> messages = new BlockingCollection<Message>();
        private static void Producer()
        {
            int ctr = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                messages.Add(new Message { Id = ctr, Name = $"Name-{ctr}" });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                ctr++;
            }
        }

        private static void Consumer()
        {
            foreach (var message in messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
                int maxchar = 102400;
                if (last_path != "")
                {
                    long length = new FileInfo(last_path).Length;
                    if (length < maxchar)
                    {
                        maxchar = maxchar - unchecked((int)length);
                        dividefile(last_path, maxchar, json);
                    }

                    else

                    {
                        dividefile("", maxchar, json);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dividefile("", maxchar, json);

                }

            }
        }

        public static void dividefile(string path, int maxchar, string message)
        {

            //FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(yourfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                Int64 x1 = stream.Length;
                char[] fileContents = new char[maxchar];
                int charsRead = streamReader.Read(fileContents, 0, maxchar);

                // Can't do much with 0 bytes
                if (charsRead == 0)
                    throw new Exception("File is 0 bytes");

                while (charsRead > 0)
                {
                    x1 = x1 - maxchar;

                    if (x1 > 0)
                    {
                        string s = new string(fileContents);
                        if (path == "")
                        {
                            last_path = Path.Combine(@"C:\TEMP", $"File-{ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.json");
                            path = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            last_path = path;
                        }
                        AppendTransaction(last_path, s);
                        charsRead = streamReader.Read(fileContents, 0, maxchar);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int m = (int)(((x1 + maxchar) % maxchar));
                        string messagechunk = new string(fileContents, 0, m);
                        if (path == "")
                        {
                            last_path = Path.Combine(@"C:\TEMP", $"File-{ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.json");
                            path = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            last_path = path;
                        }

                        AppendTransaction(last_path, messagechunk);

                        charsRead = streamReader.Read(fileContents, 0, m);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private static void AppendTransaction(string path , string  transaction)
        {
             string filename = path;
            bool firstTransaction = !File.Exists(filename);

            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            ser.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;

            using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
            {
                Encoding enc = firstTransaction ? new UTF8Encoding(true) : new UTF8Encoding(false);

                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs, enc))
                using (var jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    if (firstTransaction)
                    {
                        sw.Write("[");
                        sw.Flush();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        fs.Seek(-Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("]"), SeekOrigin.End);
                        sw.Write(",");
                        sw.Flush();
                    }

                    ser.Serialize(jtw, transaction);
                    sw.Write(']');
                }
            }


        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Producer());
            var consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Consumer());
            Console.Read();
        }
        class Message
        {
            public int ProductorThreadID { get; set; }
            public int CustomerThreadID { get; set; }
            public string key { get; set; }
            public string content { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; internal set; }
            public int Id { get; internal set; }

            public bool endThread()
            {
                return string.Compare(key, Program.BYE) == 0;
            }

            public string ToString(bool isProductor)
            {
                return string.Format("{0} Thread ID {1} : {2}", isProductor ? "Productor" : "Customer",
                                                                isProductor ? ProductorThreadID.ToString() : CustomerThreadID.ToString(),
                                                                content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to write continously  to a file with message coming from blocking collection. Once size reached to 100 kb. Stop writing and start new file

Comment: I will change it . I got it.

Comment: @user584018 right now it will work as you need and you need to specify the size using maxchar .

Comment: Thanks, are you trying to convert object (message) to byte array here?

Comment: @user584018 to stream.

Comment: I'm using `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));` instead of `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messages);`, but still I am seeing 1 message in 1 file.

Comment: what mean by this piece of code `int maxchar = 1024;
int length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path of the last file).Length;
 if (length< 1024)
 {
 maxchar =maxchar -length;

 } `

Comment: @user584018 Check the code the last file is to check if you already write to the file before and it does not reach the 100k.

Comment: Sorry, still I'm not able to compile the code, please check if you can. sorry for trouble.

Comment: Try it now. Actually `BlockingCollection<Message>` is not working on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for putting your great effort on it. A BIG Thank You!